# Google Map Android API v2 - Apply an overlay outside of a shape

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Using Google Map Android API v2, I'm trying to apply an overlay outside of a shape. For example, I would like to draw a shape around a marker an apply a grey overlay all around this shape.

Here the result I would like to have : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=221191googlemap.png

I know how to draw a shape and I know how to apply the grey overlay on all the map using the `GroundOverlay` class but I don't know how to apply the overlay on all the map except in the shape.

I really hope that somebody will be able to help me :)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try polygon overlay with holes in the middle. i.e. your entire map is covered by a polygon with an opacity value less then one. You can specify holes in the middle of the polygon. See the documents of polygon overlay:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html

It says:

```
 A polygon can be convex or concave, it may span the 180 meridian and it can have holes that are not filled in
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I missed this part of the doc !
Do you know a tools that allows me to draw a circle from a polygone ? In fact, the hole for the polygone are holy a list of LatLng, I would like to use a circleOptions or something like that.

Comment: To my knowledge, you have to specify a list of LatLng, which mimics a circle. I think it is not hard to write your own code to achieve this. I got this example through googling: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html. It is based on  web api, but you can port it to Android easily.